# fable Prophet giving null model

Tags: r, time-series, facebook-prophet, fable-r

this is my dataset

```
modi_delhi_tsib
# A tsibble: 6,576 x 21 [4h] <UTC>
   `Time Periods`      PM2.5    NO   NO2   NOx   NH3   SO2    CO Ozone Benzene Toluene  Temp    RH    WS    WD     SR    BP    AT    RF `TOT-RF`      VWS
   <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 00:00:00  549. 181.   91.2 188.   79.7  10.2 3.52   23.4   NA       NA    7.75  93.4 0.254 168.    9.05  921.  6.75     0        0 -0.00947
 2 2020-01-01 04:00:00  435. 194.   79.7 203.   66.3  11.6 3.46   29.3    9.83    NA    7.49  95.3 0.233 192.   20.7   932.  5.99     0        0 -0.0125 
 3 2020-01-01 08:00:00  453. 112.  122.  154.   74.4  10.6 2.46   30.2    9.09    NA    9.45  67.7 0.805 110.  258.    918. 11.3      0        0 -0.00434
 4 2020-01-01 12:00:00  187.  56.9 114.   91.5  74.4  12.2 1.41   30.5    3.88   104.  11.3   51.0 1.16   96.5 271.    904. 15.6      0        0  0.0549 
 5 2020-01-01 16:00:00  263.  77.4 124.  117.   74.4  13.3 2.69   18.0    5.61    96.7 10.2   69.7 0.375 157.   41.1   916. 12.5      0        0  0.0547 
 6 2020-01-01 20:00:00  725.  77.4 124.  117.   74.4  20.8 3.12   15.7    5.61   182.   8.76  89.1 0.220 185.    8.82  926.  9.50     0        0  0.0197 
 7 2020-01-02 00:00:00  541.  77.4 124.  117.   74.4  16.1 5.31   16.6    5.61   181.   8.4   92.3 0.219 183.    6.05  917.  8.52     0        0  0.0152 
 8 2020-01-02 04:00:00  428.  77.4 124.  117.   74.4  13.8 3.13   19.0    5.61   130.   8.14  94.6 0.247 186.   16.3   929.  7.62     0        0  0.0171 
 9 2020-01-02 08:00:00  383. 127.  126.  164.   74.4  22.3 1.97   23.8    7.40    92.8 10.4   68.9 0.494 145.  269.    923. 13.3      0        0  0.0359 
10 2020-01-02 12:00:00  166.  53.6 113.   86.6  74.4  16.9 0.975  28.2    4.26    26.0 11.9   46.8 0.755  80.0 268.    895. 17.9      0        0  0.0756 
# ℹ 6,566 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I want to build a prophet model to forecast the `PM2.5` variable in my dataset but on using the `prophet` function on running the following code or on changing the formulas I am getting a `null model`

```
modi_delhi_tsib |>
+     model(prophet(PM2.5~season("year", 4, type = "multiplicative")))
# A mable: 1 x 1
  `prophet(PM2.5 ~ season("year", 4, type = "multiplicative"))`
                                                        <model>
1                                                  <NULL model>
Warning message:
1 error encountered for prophet(PM2.5 ~ season("year", 4, type = "multiplicative"))
[1] 
 
> modi_delhi_tsib |>
+     model(prophet(PM2.5))
# A mable: 1 x 1
  `prophet(PM2.5)`
           <model>
1     <NULL model>
Warning message:
1 error encountered for prophet(PM2.5)
[1]
```

how can I resolve this? Thanks for the help.

This is my session info :-

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_India.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_India.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=English_India.utf8    

time zone: Asia/Calcutta
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] fable_0.3.3              feasts_0.3.1             tsibbledata_0.4.1        fpp3_0.5                 tsibble_1.1.3            fable.prophet_0.1.0.9000
 [7] fabletools_0.3.3         Rcpp_1.0.11              hms_1.1.3                patchwork_1.1.3          stringdist_0.9.10        YaleToolkit_4.2.3       
[13] lubridate_1.9.3          forcats_1.0.0            stringr_1.5.0            dplyr_1.1.3              purrr_1.0.2              readr_2.1.4             
[19] tidyr_1.3.0              tibble_3.2.1             ggplot2_3.4.3            tidyverse_2.0.0         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtable_0.3.4         anytime_0.3.9        QuickJSR_1.0.6       xfun_0.40            processx_3.8.2       inline_0.3.19        corrr_0.4.4         
 [8] callr_3.7.3          tzdb_0.4.0           vctrs_0.6.3          tools_4.3.1          ps_1.7.5             generics_0.1.3       stats4_4.3.1        
[15] parallel_4.3.1       fansi_1.0.4          highr_0.10           pkgconfig_2.0.3      prophet_1.0          distributional_0.3.2 RcppParallel_5.1.7  
[22] lifecycle_1.0.3      compiler_4.3.1       farver_2.1.1         munsell_0.5.0        codetools_0.2-19     pillar_1.9.0         crayon_1.5.2        
[29] ellipsis_0.3.2       StanHeaders_2.26.28  iterators_1.0.14     foreach_1.5.2        rstan_2.26.23        tidyselect_1.2.0     digest_0.6.33       
[36] stringi_1.7.12       colorspace_2.1-0     cli_3.6.1            magrittr_2.0.3       loo_2.6.0            pkgbuild_1.4.2       utf8_1.2.3          
[43] withr_2.5.1          rappdirs_0.3.3       prettyunits_1.2.0    scales_1.2.1         timechange_0.2.0     matrixStats_1.0.0    gridExtra_2.3       
[50] progressr_0.14.0     evaluate_0.22        knitr_1.44           rlang_1.1.1          glue_1.6.2           jsonlite_1.8.7       rstudioapi_0.15.0   
[57] R6_2.5.1
```

Comment: A NULL model indicates that there was an error during the training of the model. `
Warning message:
1 error encountered for prophet(PM2.5)
[1]  `
Without the data, I cannot reproduce this to figure out what the error might be.

Comment: hello @MitchellO'Hara-Wild thanks for replying (Also big thanks for building Fable) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n98WmUNkgqJqtyBQmXIJORqbUiFxrSdr/view?usp=drive_link . This is a link to RDS file uploaded in my drive.  The problem seem to happening in models that are added as an extension to fable namely the bsts, prophet and ata. The models present in native Fable package seem to work fine.

Comment: Also, @MitchellO'Hara-Wild I had some other questions regarding time series forecasting in general and not related to the fable package. If possible were you available in some other mode of communication? I understand if you are busy, I recently completed the book FPP3 and some questions were related to that.

Comment: Thanks for the data, there was an issue with how the {fable.prophet} package was handling the space in the index variable's name. It has been fixed in https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/fable.prophet/commit/3c458270e1904c6b355ed09bd150071120fd501d

As for bsts and ata, I don't maintain those model extensions but there could be a similar problem in them.

Comment: As for my availability for other help, I try to answer public questions like this when I have the time. The best place for stats and forecasting questions is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/. I also have limited availability for private consulting if you had questions with sensitive data.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with how the {fable.prophet} package was handling the space in the index variable's name. It has been fixed in https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/fable.prophet/commit/3c458270e1904c6b355ed09bd150071120fd501d

To resolve the issue you can install the development version of the package with

```r
# install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("mitchelloharawild/fable.prophet")
```